# why does apply_async in python not use all available workers

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

Sorry for this naive question if the answer is obvious. I feel that I am struggling with the multiprocessing module in python because I don't really know what is going on. The code is like the following:

```
pool=Pool()
for i in xrange(1000000):
    for j in xrange(i+1,1000000):
        pool.apply_async(myfun,((i,j),),callback=mycallback)
```

My idea is to parallelize this big for loop by assigning each apply_async to a core (I have 16 cores). However, only 4 or 5 out of the 16 workers are working while the others are idling. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

p.s. the callback function is very simple. It sort of makes a histogram of the values returned by myfun.

Comment: how heavy is `myfun`? if it completes too quickly, the bottleneck becomes IPC (serializing/deserializing and sending arguments/results) and invoking callbacks.

Comment: @mata, thank you for the reply. myfun multiplies several sparse matrices of size on the order of 100000. So it is not too quick but still under 1 second. I tried a very simple myfun which multiplies i and j. It turned out that only one worker was working. So I guess your answer is the one. Is there any way around to do my job? Thank you

Comment: If you multiply sparse matrices, the result can become much less sparse then the originl matrices, so depending on how sparse the result is and their representation, the serialisation of a 10e5 matrix kan be quite large, which will be a limiting factor for parallelisation. Without knowing the actual problem you're trying to solve, it's hard to tell if there's a way around this. What are you doing with the results?

Comment: @mata: the output of myfun is a scalar, which results from product of matrices and vectors. And the callback function calculates a histogram of the values of mufun. It decides to which of the 50 bins the output of myfun belongs. My workaround now is to incorporate mycallback into myfunc, and to use imap. Then it works.  Thank you for your suggestions